# PyWavelets のimport errorについて

Tags: python, macos, eclipse

Mac OS-X でPyWaveletsを使いたいのですが、エラーが生じてしまいインポートできない状態です。
対処方法を教えて頂きたいです。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/jun/Documents/workspace/Iris/IrisIRis.py", line 4, in <module>
import pywt
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/pywt/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
PILLOW_VERSION = '3.0.0'  # Pillow
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/pywt/_pywt.py", line 7, in <module>
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/pywt/_pywt.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
File "__init__.pxd", line 155, in init _pywt (/private/var/folders/7b/8tpk8d0x1mdf9tdj87mqwj6r0000gn/T/easy_install-U3Ba9H/PyWavelets-0.3.0/pywt/src/_pywt.c:38072)
ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling
```